# MS Access & Queries

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

Looking for a bit of help for an Access/Query question pertaining to a homework assignment that has 6 separate questions. I have completed all but one. The assignment wants me to do the following query.

The name, unit price, and quantity ordered for all products purchased by a customer whose id is entered from the keyboard.

Is there a function I'm overlooking for the ID entity criteria? I've looked and searched but cannot find how to add that part into the query. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Make the ID a parameter to the query.  Read more [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/using-parameters-with-queries-and-reports-HA001117077.aspx) and [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/use-parameters-to-ask-for-input-when-running-a-query-HA102809759.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by making the ID criteria a *parameter*.  Access will then pop up an input form that lets you enter the value of the parameter.

You can read more [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/using-parameters-with-queries-and-reports-HA001117077.aspx) and [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/use-parameters-to-ask-for-input-when-running-a-query-HA102809759.aspx).

Comment: That was the trick. Made the ID a parameter and when prompted enter the text and it populates with the information. Much appreciated...learned something new today.